# Set up the jobs of CI in a VM server instead of docker image

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

GitLab CI is highly integrated with Docker. But in some cases the applications need some interactions with some app (which cannot be deployed in docker)

so i want to make my jobs (on gitlab-ci.yml) be running on a Linux VM Server.

how can i set up that in Gitlab? i searched in many website but i didn't find the answer.

thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can use different executors with Gitlab. For your case, you should set up Gitlab Runner as shell executor and register it (provide it with token obtained from repo)
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html